# Flex: Reorient PopUp on browser window resize

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, popup

My footer has a bunch of tabs, each of which open up a popup window. There is a glitch though, once a popup window is open, if I resize my browser then my popup window does not auto-resize itself to match the new window configurations. Essentially, the dimensions of the popup window are static instead of being dynamic.

I want to remove this glitch, but I am not sure how I can go about achieving this. This is how I am configuring the dimensions of my popup window.

```
var stagePt:Point = new Point();
popup.x = 80;
popup.y = stagePt.y-(footerPopupContainer.height+15);
popup.drawPointerPopup(stagePt,popup);
```

One way to go about achieving this is to redraw the popup with new dimensions when the browser window is resized. Essentially a resize event will set the x and y properties for the popup above (that is if it was already open) and then call upon the drawPointerPopup method. But this isn't a fluid approach.

If the above was not a popup, and simply a div whose visibility was triggered on or off when the corresponding footer tab was clicked, then there would not be this problem. But I think this occurs coz a popup is essentially a new browser window (definitely in HTML, not sure about Flex). I, off course cannot replace this with a div coz I am dealing with legacy code.

Anyways, I must get a solution for this. Any leads are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the events option.

Add an event listener for the resize event of the view. In the handler, fire an event on the popup to resize it, or resize it from the class that added it to the stage.

This would be the most mvc way of doing it I should think.

Comment: hmm..that is actually what I mentioned, it is the option that I am currently exploring but has it's limitations because the resize is not fluid enough and is more abrupt....

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by resizing the popup from the class that added it to the stage?  thanks

Comment: Well, when you create the popup, the class that creates it will have a reference to that popup, and probably a close handler etc. If you listen for Application or Container resize events from that class, you could then resize the instance of the popup in the resize handler. Alternatively, you could extend the popup class, and add resize handlers to your custom popup. Not sure if thats any help though!